# Upgrading from Angular 4 to 7 causing problems

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular7

I have upgraded my project from **Angular 4** to **Angular 7**, and I am getting the following error:

> ERROR in node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/typeahead/typeahead.d.ts(3,10):
>   error TS2305: Module
>   '"D:/usman/dev_area/code/physician-portal/node_modules/rxjs/Observable"'
>   has no exported member 'Observable'
>
> node_modules/rxjs/Observable.d.ts(1,15): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'rxjs-compat/Observable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds an issue with rxjs-compat. Try running:

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

Comment: That is a bandaid, you are much better off investing the time to update your code to be rxjs 6 compliant. You are going to have to do it for Angular 8 so better to do it now.

Answer (score 2):

As the message said, your project cannot find the member **Observable** from `rxjs-compat`.
You can resolve that by installing the last version of `rxjs-compat` with the following command from your project folder :

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular while running is trying to search for the member **Observable** inside your **rxjs** module which is a module in  ***"node_modules"*** folder, something like *"node_modules/rxjs/Observable"*.
 You just need to install the missing module with the command:

```
npm install --save rxjs-compat
```

Answer (score 0):

rxjs-compat is not the answer you are looking for, it is a band-aid. You want to update your code to be rxjs 6 compliant and upgrade from ng-bootstrap to ngx-bootstrap.